# Why is initial webpack dev bundle so huge in JHipster?

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

I've created a new JHipster monolithic web application with Angular as a client-side framework.

After running npm start I've noticed that the file 'main.bundle.js' is around 16.6 MB.

I am aware that this bundle is supposed to be larger in development mode but I would like to reduce it as much as possible.

Are there any ways for achieving this?

Comment: Have you tried using Ahead of Time compilation? see here: https://www.w3resource.com/angular/the-ahead-of-time-compiler.php

Comment: How many entities do you have?

Comment: @atomfrede it is the initial build, with no entities.

Comment: What's the prod bundle size? 16mb sounds very huge. Maybe no treeshaking in development build?

Answer (score 0):

You should analyze your bundle with [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer), here's a [guide](https://alligator.io/angular/angular-webpack-bundle-analyzer/) about how to use it (google will find others if this goes down).

It will not solve the problem itself, but will probably reveal it.